# How to read local system without any <input> tag in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen answers directing to FileSystem API, But it is said that supported only by chrome and won't be added in W3C specification.

Almost all duplicate answers says 'no'. But they are bit old. Have someone come up with other alternative ? [ Not installing any software ]

I simply want to read a predefined directory like "`c:\\folder1`".

**Edit 1 :**
User Interaction is okay. As while accessing camera, they ask for permission. I am fine with it. I just don't want user to give me path.

Comment: No. Just no. It's a security nightmare if this were possible with just plain Javascript without user interaction or additional confirmation of any kind.

Comment: User Interaction is okay. As while accessing camera, they ask for permission ? I am fine with it. I just don't want user to give me path.

Comment: Even a confirmation dialog is still too insecure. "example.com would like to access your file system at c:\foobar". Most users would just blindly hit ok, ok, ok, because that's what they always do.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is still no, and should be no for eternity.

The major concern is security. What if just any site could access your file system? Of course, you can configure what site is allowed to see what directory, but that would be a nightmare if a lot of sites are going to use this. I don't think this is very useful. For this purpose, you have desktop applications.

Comment: I understand the concern,But then how do a HTML app ( Desktop or smartphone app) access file System ? Should be some work around ?

Comment: Maybe there is some vendor specific API for that.